# Click outside div to close, problems, in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a menu button on my site ("showmenu"), which when clicked opens up the menu div. I also have code that closes the menu if the user clicks outside of it (which I found on here)

```
// Code to open / close menu
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });

// Code for clicking outside menu to close
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $('.menu');
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.hide();
        }
    });

});
```

This code gives me problem though. I can open the menu using the "showmenu" button, but I can't click the button again to close it. The only way I can close the menu is by clicking outside of it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: And the HTML is?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
container.has(e.target).length === 0
```

Is checking if the click target is not a parent of the container element.  However, by checking that the length is equal to zero, this will evaluate to *false* when you want to check if it is *true*, i.e., to hide the container when you've clicked on one of it's parents.

Also, you need to change

```
e.target
```

to

```
$(e.target)
```

to treat it as a jquery object.

Change the line to

```
container.has($(e.target)).length > 0
```

and it should work!

Comment: Thanks for reply. I changed that, and although I can open and close the menu, I can't click outside the menu to close it.

Comment: See my edited reply. You also need to wrap e.target in $() to select it as a jQuery object